# Sails JS : Can we use different field than primary key as foreign key?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using MongoDB and SailsJS for developing a web-app.

Here are the models.

**USER MODEL**

```
    module.exports = {
      tableName : 'users',
      attributes: {
        firstname: { type: 'string', required: true, columnType: 'varchar(55)' },
        lastname: { type: 'string', required: true, columnType: 'varchar(55)' },
        email: { type: 'string', required: true, columnType: 'varchar(65)', unique: true },
        status: { type: 'number', columnType: 'tinyint(1)', defaultsTo: 1 },
        createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
        updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
        user_role: {  collection: 'userRole', via: 'user' },
      },
    };
```

**USER ROLE MODEL**

```
    module.exports = {
      tableName : 'user_roles',
      attributes: {
        role_title: { type: 'string', required: true, columnType: 'varchar(35)' },
        role_name: { type: 'string', required: true, columnType: 'varchar(35)', unique: true },
        role_code: { type: 'number', required: true, columnType: 'smallint(4)', unique: true },
        status: { type: 'number', columnType: 'tinyint(1)', defaultsTo: 1 },
        createdAt: { type: 'ref', autoCreatedAt: true, columnType: 'datetime', },
        updatedAt: { type: 'ref', autoUpdatedAt: true, columnType: 'datetime', },
        user: { collection: 'user', via: 'user_role' },
      },
    };
```

I want to use `user_role.role_code` as `foreign_key`. **Can we achieve this in Sails JS?**

Comment: Yes, we can. but keep in mind that the key should be unique.

Comment: Yes, it is unique.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#create-a-unique-index